# Find multiple words with MatchWholeWord

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a script that finds a term from a list and inserts a link to its definition using the `Range.Find` object. As I don't want to e.g. insert a link to 'cat' in 'catalogue', I use the `MatchWholeWord` property.

Now, this works well if the term is only a single word. However, if the term contains spaces or phrases, `MatchWholeWord` is simply ignored.

How can I make e.g. 'e-mail' not match 'free-mail'?

In case it matters, I use MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using FindText:="<(e-mail)>" with MatchWildcards:=True.

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
 .Execute FindText:="<(e-mail)>", MatchWildcards:=True, MatchCase:=False, _
  ReplaceWith:="blah", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Greetings

Axel